# iphone, ipadでのファイル選択

Tags: ios, monaca, iphone

monacaクラウドIDEで音楽プレイヤーを作ろうとしています。
iphone, ipadのMusicで再生できるmp3にアクセスして再生したいと考えているのですが、ディレクトリ構造（パス）が分からず困っております。
自分でできるだけ調べたのですが、答えにたどりつけなかったため、質問させてもらいます。

・そもそもcordovaのfile pluginを使ってアクセスできるものなのか？
・アクセスできるならパスがどうなるのか？

上記2点について教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

再生したいだけでしょうか？うまく質問者様のやりたいことが理解できているか自身ないですが、
まずiosでデフォルトのミュージックアプリに入っている音楽はmp3で保存されているわけではありません。
また、ミュージックアプリが保有しているファイルについても別のアプリから操作することは出来ますが、特定の命令からの操作のみを受け付けており
ファイル自体をアプリ内に複製や、別の場所に転送するなどは出来ません。
オーディオファイルの情報が欲しいのであれば[MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem)で取得できるプロパティについては参照することは出来ます。
ただ、Monacaをご使用のようなので上記情報を取得できるCordovaプラグインを探していれないといけないかと思います。

もし、ミュージックアプリに入っている音楽を再生したいのであれば下記のようなプラグインがあります。
[cordova-music-controls-plugin](https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin)
※プラグインの使用方法について疑問が発生した場合は別途質問をたててください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ファイルパスを指定して再生したいだけだったのですが、iOSには疎く、いろいろ特殊なのだと分かりました。
紹介いただいたプラグインは有料プランじゃないと使えないしと、開発をしばらく見送りそうですが、とても助かりました。